# Running tests with tcm.exe results in Field not found: 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common.WitCategoryRefName.SharedDataSet'

Tags: powershell, tfs, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests, mtm

I'm trying to run an automated test case in Microsoft Test Manager from the command line with the following command:

```
TCM.exe run /create /title:"Nightly Run" /planid:5554 /suiteid:6582 /configid:97  /collection:XXX /teamproject:XXX /include /builddir:'C:\Source\'
```

This results in the following error:

```
.\TCM.exe : Field not found: 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common.WitCategoryRefName.SharedDataSet'.
At C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\RunTest.ps1:2 char:1
+ .\TCM.exe run /create /title:"Nightly Run" /planid:5554 /suiteid:6582 /configid: ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Field not found...SharedDataSet'.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

However, this error happens on a Windows Server 2012R2 machine with Visual Studio 2013.4 installed but not on my local dev machine (Windows 10 with VS2013.4).

I know that SharedDataSets are introduced in VS2013.4 but I don't know where this error is coming from since the command doesn't give this error on my local pc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution. Running the following commands on the Windows Server fixed the error:

```
ngen uninstall Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client
ngen uninstall Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common
```